# Overloading [ (subset) function with 3 dimensions in S4 class

Tags: r, r-s4

I have an S4 class (let's call it `myclass`) that I'd like to overload the subsetting operation for.  Objects in the class can be 3 or more dimensional, and I'd like to have the extraction operator `[` work the same way it works for arrays.  Specifically, I'd like to be able to enable use of missing indices, like when subsetting R arrays (e.g. `myarray[2, ,1:3]` for a 3D array).

For 2D objects, this is not a problem.  To enable, e.g., `object[, 1:3]` I simply use `setMethod` as follows:

```
setMethod(f = "[", signature(x = "myclass", i = "missing", j = "numeric"),
  definition = function(x, i, j, k = NA, l = NA, ..., drop) {
  i <- 1:(dim(x)[1])
  return(myfun(x, i, j, k, l, ..., drop))  
})
```

Because the `[` function only has two named required arguments (`i` and `j`), I can't figure out a way to extend this to 3D or 4D objects.

I would like to create a generic `[` function, but R doesn't let me create a generic from the `[` operator: `setGeneric('[', signature=c('i', 'j', 'k'))` errors with `‘[’ is a primitive function;  methods can be defined, but the generic function is implicit, and cannot be changed.`

In John Chambers' [article](https://developer.r-project.org/howMethodsWork.pdf) on S4 classes, he seems to imply that the Matrix package does this, but I couldn't tell how they did it and looking through the Matrix source code didn't show me any obvious examples.

Comment: Actually `[` doesn't really have any _named_ arguments in the usual sense. The primitive functions match supplied arguments positionally. Furthermore you should remember that array objects take as many indices as there are dimensions.

Comment: It is true that `[` matches arguments positionally, but it still has named arguments in the sense that the signature can be matched for setMethod.  I'm not sure I understand your second point, but an object of class `myclass` is not an array object, even though it can be treated in some ways as an array such that overloading the `[` operator makes sense.